# Prop an input box when text matches a selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a multiple drop-downs like so:

```
        <select id="filter-race">
            <option>Select Race</option>
            <option>Aqua</option>
            <option>Beast</option>
            <option>Beast-Warrior</option> 
            <option>Creator-God</option>
        </select>
```

Selecting one of these selections creates a url query string `&race=Aqua` for example.

Then on page load it checks the query string and changes the dropdown:

```
if(getQueryVariable("race") != undefined){
    if(getQueryVariable("race") == "Aqua"){
        jQuery('#filter-race').prop('selectedIndex',1).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }else if(getQueryVariable("race") == "Beast"){
        jQuery('#filter-race').prop('selectedIndex',2).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
    else if(getQueryVariable("race") == "Beast-Warrior"){
        jQuery('#filter-race').prop('selectedIndex',3).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
    else if(getQueryVariable("race") == "Creator-God"){
        jQuery('#filter-race').prop('selectedIndex',4).trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
}
```

I'm going through my scripts and cleaning up a lot of my old code that I created a few years ago. I'm trying to tackle a better way of doing this with a simple match.

Something like:

```
if(getQueryVariable("race") != undefined){     
    jQuery('#filter-race').prop('selectedIndex', 'getQueryVariable("race")').trigger("chosen:updated");      
}
```

I know this code won't work but that's my thought process for what I am trying to achive. I know I should probably be using `option values` for the select but I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve what I am asking without crippling performance.

`.trigger("chosen:updated");` is needed as I am using [jQuery Chosen](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/).

Comment: why there is no value in option tag, are u using text() ?

Comment: I'm setting the query string using: var race = document.getElementById('filter-race').value; to grab the value and using it for the query string.

Comment: did you get any value in `race` ?

Comment: Yes, I get whatever value was selected in the dropdown. Example: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G9OJKP35RIT9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out an easier way than a big if else matching chain:

```
//Card Race String Query
if(getQueryVariable("race") != undefined){

    jQuery('#filter-race').val(decodeURI(getQueryVariable("race"))).trigger("chosen:updated");

    if(document.getElementById('filter-race').value == ''){
       jQuery('#filter-race').prop('selectedIndex',0);
    }   

}
```

The first line sets the select dropdown box to whatever value it picked up from `&race=` query string.

However if this was an invalid value, the dropdown box would be filled with a blank/empty value. So I followed it up by setting it so it's default value if this is the case.